# AnyLogic: Is there a way to force moveByCrane to use a worker as an resource?

Tags: anylogic

Is there a way to force moveByCrane to use a worker as a resource? in a way that worker accompanies crane position which is a common event. I can add a seize blck before the moveByCrane, but how to move worker as crane moves?

Comment: if you attach the resource to the agent, wouldn't that work? i think it might... try

Comment: @Felipe it solves, but the worker is elevated too like the agent... a little funny... no other way...?

Comment: Not very convenient, but you can play with the shape's Z-elevation on seize and release.

Comment: yes but the problem is that the worker would jump suddenly and it is a little annoying...